# NodeJS stop main function when nested callback throws an exception

Tags: node.js, express

I'm quite new to NodeJS, and I came across a construction that I can't wrap my head around. Consider the following code:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbname, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, (err) => {
        if (err) next(err);
    });

    res.render("views/page");
}
```

If an exception is raised by `Database` (for instance because `dbname` does not exist), then the callback will pass it to the Express error handler (`next`). But the code does not stop there, and it will continue to execute the next line and attempt to `render` something, which is problematic if the error handler also sends headers. If I add a `return` statement within the callback, it will simply terminate `Database` but not the rest of the function.

My question: is there anyway to prevent the rest of the code from being executed if an exception is raised?

Comment: you can always `throw err` instead of passing it into the `next` method. But you should handle it accordingly unless you want the entire system to crash

Comment: I just tried a throw-catch construction, but the process crashes with an `Uncaught Error` when I simply throw the error variable (and pass it to the handler within `catch`. How do I handle an error "accordingly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [sqlite3 npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3). Ideally, you should not be opening a database connection on every request. Instead, you should open the database connection when the server is started, and share a reference to the `db` variable to be used in the API routes (gets/posts).

Unless you just want to make it work, I believe the below should do it.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbname, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, (err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.render("views/page");
  });
}
```

EDIT: Javascript does not allow for async/await when instantiating objects, so in this case I believe would be better to just initialize the database connection outside the router method, like below, and use the `error` event to handle errors

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbname, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);
db.on('error', function(err) { /*handle error here*/ });

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) { 
    res.render("views/page");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice; I used the opening of a DB as a minimal example. In your code, you nest the subsequent business logic inside the callback. In practice, I'll have many functions with similar callbacks. Does this mean I'll have to keep nesting them (like Russian dolls) to properly handle errors? I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, there is a more elegant solution, which is to use async/awaits: https://javascript.info/async-await .. It makes the code much more readable/maintainable by preventing the callbacks chaining/callback hell. You can also use Javascript Promises, but I still prefer async/await

Comment: If you have time and it is not too much work, could you given an example of how to apply these techniques in your answer?

Comment: I just edited my answer. In this case, since the asynchronous operation is in the constructor of an object, we cannot use async/await, but I've left a suggestion there